# how to validate file_get_contents()?

Tags: php, file-io, file-get-contents

I have a file in my site, ex: `http://example.com/name.txt`

I would like to check if this file exists inside a function, so I did this

```
<?php

function checkFile($fileUrl){
   if(!is_file($fileUrl) || !is_readable($fileUrl)){
    return 'This is not valid file';
   }

}
```

Since `checkFile('http://example.com/name.txt');`  said it could not file the file, I tried to also check using this method.

```
function checkFile($fileUrl){
       $file = file_get_contents($fileUrl); 
       if(empty){
         return 'File not found or empty';
       }
    }
```

But both approach are giving me errors static that the file is not found. I am sure the file is there, so how can I actually check if files exists in online?

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can check response headers from server if 404 then file doesn't exist using function

**get_headers()**

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php

```
$file = 'http://www.domain.com/somefile.jpg';
$file_headers = @get_headers($file);
if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    $exists = false;
}
else {
    $exists = true;
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately promotes the use of @ for silencing errors, which is very bad practice. And, sadly, it is required to use get_headers() as it will ALWAYS throw a warning about something and there is nothing you can do to stop it. Which also makes it bad practice :-)

Comment: Well it solves a purpose because sometime you always need to silence errors in case of getting data from another server. Because you only need data nothing else.
Plus get_headers is not reliable i know, instead any function that is network based in unreliable because that depends on server response.

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkFile($fileUrl) {
    if (!file_exists($fileUrl)) {
        return 'This file is not a valid file.';
    }
}
```

**Side Note** This is only valid as of PHP 5
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: This is still giving me false. I used `var_dump(file_exists('http://foo.com/name.txt'))` the file already exists, but it returns false.

Comment: When I enter that into my browser I get a HTTP 500 error, which means it will return false because the file is unreachable

Comment: @user2679413 file_exists can't reach remote servers you will need to use fopen or something to check file_exists.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
# run this for 
$mime = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($url));
$extension = self::mime2ext($mime);
```

Then use this [Github mime2ext function](https://gist.github.com/marcelobns/a0a72b26a4b59fbac3d41a2d2eb76f92) to determine if a valid file is found (or the file you're expecting).